# 'Positional notation' for (semi)rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic

It's well known that, given a *basis* $b\in\mathbb N$, $b\ge2$, then each $x\in\mathbb N$, $x\ne0$ admits a unique decomposition as a sum

$$x=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb^k,$$

where $a_k\in\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}$ for all $0\le k\le n$ and $n=n(x)$ is the biggest $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\ge b^n$.

Question: is there an analogous of that fact for some class of (semi)rings, instead of $\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: It seems as if being an ordered semiring is indispensable, and I guess you'd want $0$ to be the least element. To get uniqueness maybe you need the existence of a division algorithm.  If we wanted a division algorithm, we'd also need the order to be well-founded, to ensure the algorithm terminates.  By your construction it's also countable.

Comment: Software programming languages often support positional notation for finite rings of the form $\mathbb Z/16^N\mathbb Z$.